# Setting column classes and assigning factor levels, without using a loop

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have been grappling with the following problem for a while, as I need to load in, manipulate, and produce scores from new datasets as quickly as possible. I have defined a data dictionary containing a description of each variable class (e.g. numeric, factor, character, date) and, where applicable, a list of all possible factor levels:

```
DD <- data.frame(Var = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
   Class = c("Numeric", "Factor", "Factor", "Date"),
   Levels = c(NA, "B1, B2, B3", "C1, C2", NA))

Data <- data.frame(a = 5, b = "B1", c = "C2", d = "2015-05-01")
```

Ultimately, I intend to use model.matrix to produce a design matrix with a common set of indicator variables/ columns regardless of the actual factor levels observed in the particular dataset, so I can accurately score up the data from a model.

I need to do these tasks as quickly as possible and, hence, I am trying to find a solution that avoids using lapply/ loops. Here is (a slightly convoluted version of) my existing solution for setting the factor levels, which is currently too slow for my requirements:

```
lapply(1:ncol(Data[,DD$Class=="Factor"]), function(i) {
   factor( as.character( unlist( Data[,DD$Class=="Factor"][i])) , 
   levels = unlist(strsplit(as.character(DD$Levels[DD$Class=="Factor"][i]), ", ")) )
})
```

Any suggestions for avoiding use of a loop here, if it is even possible, or any alternative solutions would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can't really avoid a loop. But you can make it more efficient by using package `data.table` to modify by reference and by avoiding `strsplit`, which means storing the levels in a more appropriate form.

Comment: And of course, I'm not convinced that all of this is really necessary. But you don't provide sufficient details to assess that.

Comment: I agree with @Roland, I answered your question but I think you are taking the convoluted way to do something quite straightforward...

Comment: If you need to go over many data files it can help to use make. I gave an example [there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115437/using-doparallel-to-cycle-through-rds-files/115828#115828).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Appreciate that this is a much simplified example, and has overly complicated code, but I'm not sure how we can avoid needing to do these tasks.  Our ultimate aim is to produce functions and a data dictionary that can process data in standard ways, such that a model can be fitted and deployed using the same set of scripts, while giving us flexibility to add additional data fields over time and apply different modelling algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

- First remark

It is inefficient to store the levels as a single string that needs to be parsed. I suggest using a list and storing the levels as a character vector directly.

```
DD <- list(a = list(class="numeric"),
           b = list(class="factor", levels = c("B1", "B2", "B3")),
           c = list(class="factor", levels = c("C1", "C2")),
           b = list(class="Date"))
```

- Second remark:

You don't need to "unfactor" your factor to add new levels.

Example:

```
fac <- factor(c("a", "b", "a"))
# two levels

factor(fac, letters)
# 26 levels, data has not changed
```

- Third remark

I don't see how to avoid a "loop" here, but lapply is an efficient way of performing loop, I doubt this is the performance bottleneck. With remarks 1 and 2, you can write a more efficient inner function. Ditching the data.frame for a data.table or a tbl may prove useful too.

Comment: Thanks! The suggestion about storing the levels in a list seems very sensible.  Reassuring to know that we need to use a loop - hopefully we can reduce the processing time substantially following some more tweaks of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define column classes (and hence levels for your factors) right when you create your data frame:

```
mylevels <- c("b1","b2","b3","c1","c2") 

myData <- data.frame(a =
numeric(), b = factor(levels=mylevels), c = factor(levels=mylevels), d
= character())
```

This creates a blank data frame that you can fill up later.

In reply to your comment: rbind will only work if  *myData* has same column classes as *data*. Otherwise column classes will change. My point is: if data that you load is similar (has same number of columns, columns have same names, etc.) then you can set classes right when you load that data, something like:

```
myclasses <- c(“numeric”,”factor”,”factor”,”date”)
myData <- read.table(“mydatafile.csv”, sep=”,”, header = TRUE, colClasses = myclasses)
myLevels <- c(“a1”,”a2”,”b1”,”b2”)
myfactorlist <- c(“b”,”c”)
levels(myData[,myfactorlist]) <- myLevels
```

here I assume your column names are as in previous example: “a”,”b”,”c”,”d”, where "c" and "b" are factor columns.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like an interesting solution, but not sure how I would populate the blank data frame with the data.  Wouldn't something like rbind(myData, Data) create a matrix and eliminate the variable classes?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have iterate over the columns but it could be done in a bit cleaner fashion like this.  We have assumed you want to preserve the input data frame so we create a new data frame, `Data2` to hold the result.  Note that we have made the columns of `DD` character rather than factor.  `Data` is from the question.

```
DD <- data.frame(Var = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
   Class = c("Numeric", "Factor", "Factor", "Date"),
   Levels = c(NA, "B1, B2, B3", "C1, C2", NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data2 <- Data

# factors
Factors <- subset(DD, Class == "Factor")
Levels <- strsplit(as.character(Factors$Levels), ", ")
Data2[Factors$Var] <- Map(factor, Data2[Factors$Var], Levels)

# dates
Dates <- subset(DD, Class == "Date")
Data2[Dates$Var] <- Map(as.Date, Data2[Dates$Var])
```

giving:

```
> str(Data2)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num 5
 $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "B1","B2","B3": 1
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "C1","C2": 2
 $ d: Date, format: "2015-05-01"
```